# Get the most recent documents without duplicates based on a single property

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to select all documents in a collection where an item should only be returned if it is the most recent (based on a `"created"` property) and distinct (based on the values in a property `"module"`).

The schema is in the following form (highly simplified version):

```
[
    {
        "created": "2020-11-22 15:06:07.331503",
        "module": "module1",
        "md5": "ee35165603518835bd9cf",
        "version": "1.0",
    },
    {
        "created": "2019-10-12 15:06:07.331503",
        "module": "module1",
        "md5": "e535165403518835bd3jd",
        "version": "0.0",
    },
    {"module": "module1"},
    {"module": "module2"},
    {"module": "module2"},
    {"module": "module3"},
]
```

Said differently, I only want the most recent documents without any duplicates based on the `"modules"` property.

```
{
    "created": "2020-11-22 15:06:07.331503",
    "module": "module1",
    "md5": "ee35165603518835bd9cf",
    "version": "1.0",
},
{"module": "module2"},
{"module": "module3"},
```

SQL queries are most definitely not my strongest, and I'm having trouble putting a query together that returns all elements but duplicates, while also being sorted. The simplest case I can think of is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.module
FROM c
```

But that is obviously not what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a single query. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL:

```
SELECT c.module,max(c.created) as latest FROM c group by c.module
```

This SQL can only get two properties. if you want to get whole document, you can refer to this [How do I get the latest record for each item in CosmosDB using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712120/how-do-i-get-the-latest-record-for-each-item-in-cosmosdb-using-sql/64749123#64749123).