# How to query latest N records with max(timestamp) where item type is not duplicated in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with Azure SQL CosmosDB. I am trying to query records with the highest timestamp where item type is not duplicated. My database looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "colorType": "red",
    "colorValue": 100,
    "measurements": [],
    "_ts": 1610966083
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "colorType": "red",
    "colorValue": 59,
    "measurements": [],
    "_ts": 1610966096
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "colorType": "blue",
    "colorValue": 32,
    "measurements": [],
    "_ts": 1610966096
},
...
```

I need two queries:

1. First query should gives me a group of items with non duplicated colorType and max(_ts) for specific colorType.

I tried with query:

```
SELECT MAX(t._ts) AS _ts,
       t.colorType,
       MAX(t.colorValue) AS colorValue
FROM colorsTable t 
GROUP BY t.colorType
```

which gives me

```
[
{
    "_ts": 1610966297,
    "colorType": "blue",
    "colorValue": 32
},
{
    "_ts": 1610966306,
    "colorType": "red",
    "colorValue": 100
}
]
```

It is almost what I would like to achieve, but I would like to add field measurements, which is nested json. That is why I can't use MAX() on it. How can I solve it?

2. Second query should gives me N groups of items with non duplicated colorType and max(_ts) for specific type inside each group. N is the number of groups. I need multiple groups to draw a chart with archive data.

I tried with different query, where I query for a single colorType. Then it gives me good resault where I can choose LIMIT N. But how can I combine multiple query into one? I tried with UNION, UNION ALL, but it seems that is doesn't work wit Azure SQL. Maybe there is a better approach or a query for this?

```
SELECT *
FROM colorsTable t
WHERE t.colorType = "red"
ORDER BY t._ts DESC
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM table t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 from table tt
         WHERE tt.type = t.type
          and tt.timestamp > t.timestamp);
```

Comment: It doesn't work: Failed to query item for container table. Identifier 'table' could not be resolved.

I think that Azure has a problem with SELECT t.* or SELECT 1 from table tt

Comment: **Identifier 'table' could not be resolved.** can you please replace your original table name with `table` in query and share your query if you still face the issue.

Comment: Ok, I edited first post. My query:
SELECT t.*
  FROM colorsTable t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 from colorsTable tt
         WHERE tt.colorType = t.colorType
          and tt._ts > t._ts);

gives: Failed to query item for container colorsTable:
{"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":9,"end":10},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '*'."}]}

if I remove it then the error is: "Identifier 'colorsTable' could not be resolved."}]}

Answer (score 0):

> It is almost what I would like to achieve, but I would like to add
> field measurements, which is nested json. That is why I can't use
> MAX() on it. How can I solve it?

This is not supported. There is no [aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-aggregate-functions#types-of-aggregate-functions) to achieve your requirement in Cosmos DB.

> Second query should gives me N groups of items with non duplicated
> colorType and max(_ts) for specific type inside each group. N is the
> number of groups. I need multiple groups to draw a chart with archive
> data.

There is no SQL to get this result. Maybe you can try to implement a materialized view using change feed. You can refer to [How do I get the latest record for each item in CosmosDB using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712120/how-do-i-get-the-latest-record-for-each-item-in-cosmosdb-using-sql/64749123#64749123).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this isn't the approach I was looking for. I will stay with sending separate request for each type.