# Azure Cosmos DB api SQL last mesure for each element

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Cosmos DB container "mesure" like this :

```
{
"cdreseau": "035000544",
"date": "2020-12-09",
"element": "PH",
"val": 7.1
}
{
"cdreseau": "035000544",
"date": "2020-14-09",
"element": "CA",
"val": 20.1
}...
```

I would like ton find last mesure value and date for each element in a "cdreseau"

I can get last date foreach element with that :

```
SELECT MAX(c.date) as date,c.element FROM c where c.cdreseau='040000422' group by c.element
```

But how can i get the c.val of the item in the same request ? /date,/cdreseau,/element is unique key

regards

Comment: Have you considered ordering your query by date and retrieving the first result?

Comment: if i do that à can't havec all c.element value, that's work for one element but not for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't achieve by SQL in Cosmos DB. You can create a new container which save the latest values of your elements. Or you can implement a materialized view using change feed.
Ref: [How do I get the latest record for each item in CosmosDB using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712120/how-do-i-get-the-latest-record-for-each-item-in-cosmosdb-using-sql)

Comment: thank's i will create a new container with lasted values and load it with ADF